# node-inspector error 'ReferenceError: window is not defined'

Tags: debugging, jasmine, node-inspector

With node-inspector, when running `node-debug whatever.js` file I get

> 'ReferenceError: window is not defined'

If I try to run `node-debug whateverSpec.js` I get

> 'ReferenceError: describe is not defined'

My environment is:

- Win7
- [Jasmine-npm](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm) for the test
- [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector#known-issues)
- The test command in package.json is 'jasmine'

What could be the problem?

Comment: You need to execute `whateverSpec.js` in the Jasmine context. Without it NodeJS „doesn’t know” what `describe` means. The command will look like `node-debug node_modules/.bin/jasmine` (if you are using cygWin) or `node-debug node_modules\.bin\jasmine` on pure Windows console

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski `$ node-debug node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js whateverSpec.js` is the way to proceed in windows to avoid the error: `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')") 
^^^^^^^ 

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list `